# Porque o subheader não está sendo exibido?

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Estou tentando criar uma barra para busca, estou usando o `bar-subheader` para isso, mas não exibe. Como fazer isso ?

```
<ion-view view-title="Empresas">

  <div class="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset padding">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="pesquisar">
    </label>
  </div>

  <ion-content class="padding has-footer has-subheader">

        <ion-list>      
            <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left" 
                  ng-repeat="item in items | filter:pesquisar" 
                  type="item-text-wrap"
                  ng-click="getEmpresa({{item.Empresa.id}})" >

                <img ng-src='{{item.Empresa.imagem}}'>          
                <div style="font-weight:bold;" class="item-text-wrap">{{item.Empresa.nome}}</div>
                <div style="font-size:small" class="item-text-wrap">{{item.Empresa.tipo}}</div>
                <div style="font-size:small">{{item.Empresa.endereco}}</div>
                <div style="font-size:small">{{item.Empresa.telefone}}</div>

                <a href="tel:{{item.Empresa.telefone}}" class="button button-small button-balanced icon ion-ios-telephone">
                </a> 

            </ion-item>
            <ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore();" distance="1%" ng-if='!moreData'></ion-infinite-scroll>
       </ion-list>

  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Comment: Se colocar dentro do `<ion-content>` exibe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvido. O problema era que o subheader que eu estava criando ficava atrás das tabs, então criei um css para esse subheader e funcionou como precisava.

ficou assim.

```
.search-subheader {
    top:85px;   
}
```

Comment: Oi Fernando, bom saber que você resolveu. Quando voltar aqui, marque sua prórpria resposta como aceita, ok?